# What is a word for someone who has a tendency to almost change everyone around him, in a good or bad way?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word would be used for a person who changes or has a lot of influence on others around him, and it can be in both bad and good way.

Comment: 'Influential' when standalone is usually 'for good' when used in the 'influence others' rather than 'able to exert power' sense.

Comment: **Charismatic** people have an innate ability to influence others for the better (Churchill) or worse (Hitler).

Comment: @WeatherVane That's what I was thinking. Lexico: Exercising a compelling charm which inspires devotion in others.

Comment: For a noun, [**influencer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influencer) seems the most obvious. If that's not appropriate, why isn't it? What *particular* aspect of somebody being an influencer are you looking for? (And do you want a noun or an adjective?) Please provide more sentence and an example sentence with a space into which the word would be placed.

Comment: The word first arising in my mind was [catalyst](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/catalyst).

Comment: These are interesting and valid but I'm going with *Manipulative*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the word **charistmatic**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/charismatic) has

> **charismatic**
> ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** Exercising a compelling charm which inspires devotion in others.

There are some well known examples of such people, for example [Adolf Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) who motivated people to take the path towards hatred and war, and [Winston Churchill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill) who encouraged the allies to rise against him.